# I can not make rating bar in android studio

Tags: ratingbar

How to make rating bar in android studio, perhaps it can show the sample of xml and also the code(main.activity)?

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you could include some code with your question, including things you've already tried and other resources you've attempted to use that haven't yet answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you new for android Studio then do not worry about it.
google officially go on android studio.

buy the way you want android Studio example with source of xml file in main activity.

**First How to add?**
1. In your build.gradle add latest appcompat library.

```
dependencies {  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:X.X.X' // where X.X.X version
}
```

2. Make your activity extend android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       ...
   }
3. Declare your RatingBar inside any layout.xml file.

   android:rating="3.5"
       android:rating="3.5"
       android:stepSize="0.5"
       android:numStars="5"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

[Android Rating Bar Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIbA6.png)

I am developing all material design stuffs for newbie developers so they can learn easly Android.. this is my site helping you how to create **MATERIAL DESIGN STUFF'S** in Android..

And for Rating Bar with Material Design this may be helps you http://exandroidstudio.blogspot.in/2015/11/rating-bar-material-design-tips.html